# Create event listener for 'Set' button of DatePicker dialogue

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm working on this android application in which user clicks on pick date button and the date picker dialogue box pops up, user can set the date and press the set button of the dialogue box. I am not able to get the event listener behind set button. I want to get the date user has set in that dialogue box behind that set button.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations);


        pickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDateButton);
          final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            month = month + 1;

        pickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

            }
        });

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fdf",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tracking Stopped",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

        }
    };
```

Have i wrote the right listener? it's not displaying the toast message inside the listener so its not coming inside it when user presses set button and closes the dialog.

Comment: Edit your post and include the `showDialog` code or wherever you show the `DiatePickerDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most part you are doing right but try doing it this way.

```
 static final int DATE_PICKER_ID= 999;

 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {


            case DATE_PICKER_ID: 

        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener , year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // onDateSet method
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


        //your code here
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah your listener is correct, but you didn't set the listener of your dialog. So I suggest you to override method onCreateDialog. Like the above code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_PICKER_ID:

        // open datepicker dialog. 
        // set date picker for current date 
        // add pickerListener listner to date picker
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}
```

this way your activity is going to listen the changes in the instance of DatePickerDialog you just created.

Since showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID) and onCreateDialog(int id) are deprecated. I suggest you to create your own instance of DatePickerDialog without using those methods. Like

```
pickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
    });
```